# {BATCH} How to see if numbers are multiples of each other

Tags: batch-file

Is there a simple way to tell if a number is multiple of another? For example, can I check is a certain year (2015,2016,2017) is a multiple of say, 4? 
Thanks in advance!
-Zackary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the *modulus* operator. In most languages it's `%`, but since Batch uses that symbol for variables, it's defined as `%%`.

This computes the remainder of the division. So you can check like this:

```
set /a mod=2015 %% 4
if %mod%==0 echo
```

If the remainder of 2015/4 is 0, then 2015 is a multiple of 4.

Answer (score -2):

You mean from a Windows command prompt? Can you use powershell at least?
If not, you can generate every possible multiple of 4 using

for /l %l in (4,4,3000) do if "%l"=="%value%" *{do whatever}*

Comment: That's a pretty inefficient method when the modulus operator exists.

Comment: Well, supposedly the answers are posted by people that know how to solve the questions! **`;)`**. BTW, you may also use the same loop to generate every possible multiple of 4 in powershell, isn't it?